# Filters in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I am migrating my application from Struts1 to Struts2.

In my Struts1 application, I have a filter chain implemented by two filters(Filter1.java, Filter2.java).
And also I've overriden the ActionServlet class.
Below is how these components are configured in web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
    <filter-class>MyFilter1</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>MyFilter2</filter-class>

    ...init params...

</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>InitServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyActionServlet</servlet-class>
    ..........
    ..........
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyActionServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Basically, when ever a request comes to my application, it is intercepted by these two filters(in doFilter() method) and then this request is given to the Action servlet.

### Filter1.java:

```
public void doFilter(....) {
    ......
    if (condition) {
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    else {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("someJSPPage");
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);
    }
    ......
}
```

### Filter2.java:

```
public void doFilter(....) {
    ......
    if (condition) {
        //some logic
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    else {
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    ......
}
```

How can I have these filters implemented in Struts2. In Struts2 the front controller itself is a filter(org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter). 
I've written the logic of those two filters in the new Struts2 filter StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter, but am not getting into issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want, but AFAIK there is nothing wrong per se with having your own filters while at the same time using Struts2.

Comment: Help with what, precisely?